# How to change instance attributes in python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting up with python classes and I have some doubts about how to properly change values in instance attributes:

I have the following example:

```
import numpy as np

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "none"
        self.val = np.array([])
```

Instances of `myClass` will have two attributes: `name` and `values`.

After creating an object of `myClass`

```
obj1 = myClass()
```

I would like to change the variable `name` and `val` of `obj1`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

doing:

```
obj1.name="name1"
obj1.val = np.zeros(3)
```

or creating member function to define this:

```
def setName(self, name):
    self.name = name

def setVal(self, arr):
    self.val = arr

obj1.setName("name2")
obj1.setName(np.zeros(3))
```

If I want to loop through the `val` arr can I:

```
for i in range(3):
    obj1.val[i] = i
```

Or should I create a function to assign entry "i" in the array

```
def setValI(self, i, val):
    self.val[i] = val
```

and use it in the loop as:

```
for i in range(3):
    obj1.setValI(i, i)
```

Or is it all the same and I can use whatever approach I want?

Kind regards

Comment: What do you want your users to do?  If you don't mind them setting attributes directly, that's by far the easiest solution.  If you need to validate or filter what gets written there, then the `setName` and `setVal` methods are common.

Comment: In generell set and get function are th emote elegant way I would say. And for your list or your array - if u initialize an empty list/array and want to assign a value to e.g. Position 2 you'll get an index error

Comment: @TimRoberts. The user will not do anything. I have some files to read and given the structure of the data I would like to create my own class to store it. It will have a name and a couple other information along with numerical values. Since I do not know the size of the array I will have to define I am creating an empty array and latter will read file information to prealocate the vector some size and afterwards populate it will information from the file. I just don't know with one of these syntaxes is doing unwanted copies. The data to store inside the array can be quite large.

Comment: @Cris what do you mean by index error? In the example code above, the numpy array is being resized with both approaches without any error.

Comment: There's always a user.  Sometimes it's the programmer that wrote the code.  So, do what makes sense.  I, personally, would not provide element-by-element access functions for an array, because then you lose the benefits of np vectorization.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the reply. Given that I gave to go line-by-line in the file to collect information what would you suggest? I don't know if in this case the np vectorization will play an effect. Would it be better to create a temporary np.array (`tmpVector`), populate it and perform `obj1.setVal(tmpVector)` ? wouldn't I be doing unnecessary copying of variables?

Comment: Remember that Python never copies data, unless you specifically go out of your way to ask for it.  When you do an assignment, you are just making a new reference to a single object.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to change your `__init__` to require two arguments:

```py
import numpy as np

class myClass:
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val

# Create an instance of myClass
obj1 = myClass("name1", np.zeros(3))
```

If you want to change the values of `name` and/or `val` use **getter** and **setter** methods as you shouldn't access instance variables outside of the class itself.

As you don't have `private` instance variables, it's just an agreement, that you don't access the variables directly. You can also go ahead and add one underscore before your instance variables, to highlight that these should be treated as **private** variables:

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, name, val):
      # Underscore to signal "private" variable
      self._name = name
      self._val = val
```

Comment: What syntax would you use to loop through the `val` numpy array and assign values to each _ith_ entry?

Comment: Create a method for that too. Otherwise you'd try to access the `val` instance variable outside of the class again. It's possible but bad style.